# Isotope won't sort alphabetically

Tags: jquery, sorting, jquery-isotope

I'm trying to extract text and sort that text alphabetically with the isotope library..the text is in each p tag with the class of .box-title.  I'm passing a function to get that text via the getSortData option..... but this is not working. Any ideas why? I've inspected $container, $elem and $('.box-title') and they both return arrays of data

```
$container.isotope({
    getSortData: {
        name: function ($elem) {
            return $elem.find('.box-title').text();
        }
    }
});
$container.isotope({
    sortBy: 'name'
});
```

Comment: I realized I need to sort before I filter... that seemed to work at least for me.. not sure if this is always the case

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in your code.

```
name: function (elem) {
            return $(elem).find('.box-title').text();
      }
```